# Docker AspNet Core + Couchbase

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, windows-10, couchbase

I have a .net core api which includes the required couchbase-sdk installed 
The api has docker support through visual studio. I added couchbase section in the docker-compose file to use couchbase, when I run the docker-compose up command both the api and couchbase is running. I am able to view the couchbase UI.

Question: what will my connectionstring be in the appsettings.json file to connect to this couchbase cluster because its running inside docker which will have its ip addresses. I cannot simply go localhost:8091?

In the compose file, how do I set the username and password, default bucket to use in couchbase, I had a look at the docs on docker/couchbase and couldnt find anything, couldnt find much docs on google about this also.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use the hostname, not IP, and that hostname will be the service name in the docker-compose.yml file. In other words, use `db`.

Comment: Please see comment below. I think some sort of setup in the compose file needs to be done in order to tell Couchbase to use a specific bucket and set a username and password. I dont know what these ENV variables are..

Comment: @OptimusPrime I don't think there *are* environment variables for that, is the point I was trying to make in my answer. I think you need to write a script to use  Couchbase's cli or REST to do that. I've asked some of the engineers within Couchbase to take a look and correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

All the documentation about Couchbase on Docker can be found here: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/install/getting-started-docker.html and there's also some quick-start information here: https://hub.docker.com/_/couchbase

When you say the "connection string" for Couchbase, this is normally the IP address or network address of one or more Couchbase nodes. Since you are using docker-compose, I think "db" might be what you use instead.

As for your other questions: "how do I set the username and password, default bucket to use in couchbase" -> there is no way that I know of currently to do this with docker or docker compose using the off-the-shelf docker images supplied by Couchbase. If you want to automate this, you could create your own docker image (based on the Couchbase image) that runs a script (details too long for this SO answer, but you could [check out this blog post](https://blog.couchbase.com/using-docker-develop-couchbase/), for instance).

Alternatively, there is a Kubernetes operator that is capable of doing exactly this (for Couchbase Enterprise only), which I guess isn't too helpful if you're set on using docker-compose.

Comment: In my project I have the following nuget package "Couchbase.Extensions.DependencyInjection". I did set the connectionstring to "db" and when I try use the sample bucket "travel-sample" I get the following error: "Couchbase.Configuration.Server.Serialization.BootstrapException: 'Could not bootstrap - check inner exceptions for details. (Authentication failed for user 'travel-sample') (Could not bootstrap with CCCP. (Authentication failed for user 'travel-sample')) " Now I think some setup needs to be done before running the container in the compose file. some ENV variables need to be set?

Comment: You might want to post that code. It sounds like you didn't supply authentication credentials.

Comment: I tried a few ways to provide the authentication credentials, I also followed the article you posted above to create an image based on the couchbase image, still no luck, have a look at the code, here is the repo "https://github.com/bin-debug/MicroServiceTest"

Comment: @OptimusPrime I think one of the problems is here: https://github.com/bin-debug/MicroServiceTest/blob/master/MicroSvr/ExampleTwoSrv/Startup.cs#L37 - First, I'd recommend using Servers instead of ConnectionString. Second, you haven't specified any credentials. You'd typically specify a username and password (which you'll need to first create in Couchbase)

Comment: Using the couch base dependency injection servers takes in a list of URI. Also I tried to find if couch base comes with a default username and password and I couldn't find anything about it. When you run the container you have to set it up by creating a username and password. I'm not sure if you can pass it environment variables in my docker file also. I don't think anybody has successfully done this...

Comment: There is no default username/password for Couchbase. You can set it up via the UI or you can write a script to do it with REST or CLI, but afaik there is no way of doing this by passing in environment variables with the default image

Comment: Okay, let me try creating it via rest. I'll also research the cli method.

Comment: So I am trying to create the image and run a script inside to do the initial setup, I done some reseach online and managed to put this together but I am not sure where I am going wrong, I can access the couch WEB UI but I cant execute any curl commands to this URL. These are my docker files and entrypoint "https://github.com/bin-debug/MicroServiceTest/tree/master/WIP"

Comment: It just says starting couch base server and logs are available, basically printing out that line. And when I open the webUI for couch in my browser, it's not configured which means it didn't set the username or password as yet, I wait awhile because I read somewhere that it takes about 4 mins to setup. Atleast now a custom image is being built, it's just something small in this entry point script that I am missing for it not to work, so atleast some progress was made.